# Prallel processing using multiprocessing pool outside __main__

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, multiprocessing, pool

I have a requirement to extract data from BigQuery and post the data to an end point.

End point can only accept one request at a time so if post one row at the time it is too slow so I decided to use multiprocessing pool to be able to post the requests in parallel. However the multi processing logic is not in **main** so I am having issues with this.

we use this module for multiple purposes so the structure is as below and my logic of posting data from BQ to an api resides in operator3.services

```
__main__.py
   cli.py
     operator1.py
        services.py
     operator2.py
         services.py
     operator3.py
         services.py
```

As my multiprocessing logic is in operator3.services and because this is not **main** this logic is never getting invoked.

We call this module from a DAG with entry point as **main**.py and we pass a parameter to let **Main** decide which operator to run.

The logic I have in services.py

```
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())
            response = pool.map(self.post_to_eventservice.post_sales_to_eventservice, payload_list)
            for res in response:
                sale_unique_id = res["salesDataUniqueId"]
                status_code = res["status_code"]
                print(f"sale unique id is:{sale_unique_id}")
                if status_code in (200, 204):
                    logging.info(f"Response code from API: {status_code}")
                    log_payload = res
                    log_responses.append(log_payload)
                    logging.info(f"Successfuly posted sale event:{sale_unique_id}")
                else:
                    log_payload = res
                    log_responses.append(log_payload)
                    logging.info(f"Unable to post sale event:{sale_unique_id}")
```

Any idea how I can implment multiprocessing this case?

I tested this locally by calling opeartor3.services.py and the logic works as in this case operator3 is the main if I call that directly.